# How to split specific String From HTML

Tags: android, html

Hello i have this html from Api how i can get specific string from this html ?

```
 <div class="field-content"><span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2017-10-21T00:00:00+03:00">21 أكتوبر 2017</span></div>  </div>        
                                                         <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/news/%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B4-%D9%85%D8%A4%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86">رحلة الى لبنان على هامش مؤتمر صيادلة لبنان</a></span>  </div>        
                                                         <div class="views-field views-field-field-brief">        <div class="field-content">تعلن نقابة الصيادلة عن تسيير رحلة الى لبنان على هامش مؤتمر صيادلة لبنان من تاريخ\
                                                        (16- 20 /11/2017)
                                                       </div>  </div>  </div>        
                                                         <div class="views-field views-field-view-node">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/news/%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B4-%D9%85%D8%A4%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86">اقرأ المزيد</a></span>  </div>    
                                                         </div>
                                                         <div class="row views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
                                                             <div class="col-xs-3">    
                                                         <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="node/3457"><img src="/sites/all/themes/dotstrap/images/news-default.png" border="0" /></a></div>  </div>  </div>      <div class="col-xs-9">
```

i need from this just  21 أكتوبر 2017 and

تعلن نقابة الصيادلة عن تسيير رحلة الى لبنان على هامش مؤتمر صيادلة لبنان من تاريخ\

and i store this in String variable like this

```
String Text = separated[1].toString();
```

Comment: what have you tried? maybe try it yourself and come back if it doesnt work then show us the code you tried

Comment: What if the string is repeated in the same html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HTML parser (e.g [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org)) to extract what you need. You can use XPath inside select() method to extract only important part of html.

Sample getter for date:

```
public static String getDate(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).select("span.date-display-single").text();
}
```

Comment: thank you for replay ,, i tried this but how i can get string in this case ?

Comment: What do you mean? This sample method returns String.

Comment: now i  tried to get this /sites/all/themes/dotstrap/images/news-default.png do u have idea

Comment: please if you have any idea to get the url tell me !

Comment: return Jsoup.parse(html).select("div.views-field-field-image img").attr('src');